# Gridview to dataset asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, dataset, report-viewer2012

I have a gridview connect to a sqldatasource that I need to convert to a dataset. The reason I want to  make the gridview to dataset is to use the dataset in reportviewer.Anyone know how to do this? or is their a better way to view a gridview in reportviewer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp:SqlDataSource to DataSet Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035714/aspsqldatasource-to-dataset-items)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I can post this before your question gets deleted for not being specific....

You can go directly from an SqlDataSource to a DataSet:

[asp:SqlDataSource to DataSet Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035714/aspsqldatasource-to-dataset-items)

Comment: Steve Wellens you should consider deleting this answer. This is not an answer, this should be a comment. Its against SO policy to post here. Not flagging this are you are YOU :)